# Access list in razor model from jQuery and select next element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, list, razor, model

I have a List in a razor view and i want change active element when user click on it's title. I hold active element index number in hidden and wrote a jQuery click handler to change that. This way is about get elements by accessing model from jQuery and get next element by index+1 but i can't push new index in @Model expression. this is my code:

```
$("#title").on("click", function () {
  var idx = $('#hdn_Idx').val() + 1;
  var id = $("#hdn_Id").val();
  var nextElement = '@Model.elementList[idx].id';
});
```

I don't want to use some ajax method because i have List in model of view and don't need to calculate again. What can i do? or is the better way exist to do this?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does your view look like? I want to understand how you are handling the model inside the view.

Comment: You cannot push JS elements directly into the Razor element.  Save the list into JS object and push into that list.  It is also one direction you can pass stuff in Razor to JS but you can pass JS to Razor

Comment: Christo8989 and imGreg Thanks for your heeds. This is an issue I faced months ago. I'll check it and write result ASAP. Thanks again.